# Is there a flag/option available to display only bad checksum packets using tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I can see tshark/wireshark has a flag to display only packets with checksum errors (tcp.checksum.status == "Unverified"). I tried checking if there is any similar flag in tcpdump, I couldn't find it. Is there a flag/option available with tcpdump? If so any one knows what it is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, `tcpdump` only offers the filters specified [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html). This does not include an option to filter checksum.

However, you can easily filter checksum incorrect packets using grep:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -vvv tcp | grep incorrect
```

Otherwise your best option is to use tshark.